# The most elegant way to abstract away repeated, non-interatable calls

Tags: embedded, abstraction

On an embedded system, I have a library that provides specific calls for each port, such as `__PORTA_ENABLE(pin)`, `__PORTB_ENABLE(pin)`, `__PORTn__WRITE(pin, val)`, `__PORTn_TIMERm(pin, period)` and so on. I have to initialize 8 arbitrary, but pre-defined, pins on assorted ports A through D to the same state, and it takes about 30 lines to initialize each port. At the moment, I'm copy-pasting the initialization block 8 times, as so:

```
__PORTA_ENABLE(4);
__PORTA_SETMODE(4, OUTPUT);
__PORTA_TIMER_B_(4, 2000);
///... and so on
__PORTA_ENABLE(5);
__PORTA_SETMODE(5, OUTPUT);
__PORTA_TIMER_C_(5, 2000);
///... and so on
__PORTB_ENABLE(7);
__PORTB_SETMODE(7, OUTPUT);
__PORTB_TIMER_A_(7, 2000);
///... and so on
__PORTB_ENABLE(2);
__PORTB_SETMODE(2, OUTPUT);
__PORTB_TIMER_F_(2, 2000);
///... and so on
```

Obviously this would be trivial if the designers of the abstraction layer used a call like `GPIO_ENABLE(int port, int pin)`, but they didn't, so here I sit. Is there an elegant way to abstract this away and prevent this from ballooning into a 300 line, unmaintainable mass of copy-pasta?

Comment: Why can't you just write `GPIO_ENABLE` yourself?

Comment: @isaach1000 mainly time constraints: I'm trying to pretty up the code, and the abstraction layer is insanely complex (11 MB of C code) in order to be portable to many different chips in the same family; I'd prefer to use the API-defined calls to maintain that portability.

Comment: I mean just write your own utility function as a static function or something so that you only use it where you need it. I'm not suggesting you add to the original API.

Comment: So what is your question, exactly? How to extract a bunch of common/repetitive code into a function?

Answer (score 0):

Use a token pasting macro that does the initialization and then call it individually for each pin.

The macro defines the common initialization functionality:

```
#define INIT_PIN(port, pin, timer) \
    __PORT ## port ## _ENABLE(pin);          \
    __PORT ## port ## _SETMODE(pin, OUTPUT); \
    __PORT ## port ## _TIMER_ ## timer ## _(pin, 2000);
```

The pin-specific initialization is then:

```
INIT_PIN(A, 4, B);
INIT_PIN(A, 5, C);
INIT_PIN(B, 7, A);
INIT_PIN(B, 2, F);
```